# Installing egit on PHP Eclipse but I am getting an error

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Git integration for Eclipse - Source Code 5.5.1.201910021850-r     (org.eclipse.egit.source.feature.group 5.5.1.201910021850-r)
Missing requirement: Git integration for Eclipse 5.5.1.201910021850-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group     5.5.1.201910021850-r) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.12.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Git integration for Eclipse - Source Code 5.5.1.201910021850-r     (org.eclipse.egit.source.feature.group 5.5.1.201910021850-r)
To: org.eclipse.egit.feature.group [5.5.1,5.6.0)
```

Anyone familiar with this? I'm trying to install EGit on my Eclipse Helios.

Answer (score 0):

This is saying that at least version 3.12.0 of the `org.eclipse.core.runtime` plug-in is required. Eclipse Helios only has version 3.6.0.

Eclipse Helios is 9 years and 13 releases out of date. Try using a newer Eclipse (2019-09 is the current release).